# py2exe strange missing modules

Tags: python, py2exe

I think this is one of the many questions about missing modules and py2exe... anyway...

1. PylibUty is a local package located in C:\Dati\workspaces\PythonEclipse\APyLibUty\PyLibUty and referred in every .py file with:

   import sys, os
   sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname("**file**"), '..'))
   sys.path.append("C:/Dati/workspaces/PythonEclipse/APyLibUty")
   from PyLibUty.pystr import randomString, insertStr
2. uuid is a Python package so I normally import it
3. _posixshmem I am not able to find what package I should install using pip/pipenv
4. resource: I installed both resource and pyresource using pip/pipenv bat nothing changed

What should I install or import to solve these problems?

This is the output produced running py2exe:

[image]

Comment: I found the solution for the 1st missing module, just adding:

import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')) 
sys.path.append("C:/Dati/workspaces/PythonEclipse/APyLibUty")

to setup.py and it disappears

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a solution to understand what modules I should add or install to clear the problems of py2exe, so I searched the web to find a different tool able to make exe files from Python sources. I found cx_freeze, actually it does not produce the errors I reported so at the moment I switched to cx_freeze. I will test it better but at the moment my problem is solved.

Comment: I can confirm Massimo's answer. I was unable to solve the missing-module problems with py2exe and ended up using cx_freeze which works great for me.

Comment: At the moment I tested cx_freeze with a couple of applications using bcrypt, certifi, cryptography,  JsonForm, JsonSir, passlib, PyReadline, PySocks, pywin32, ttable, urllib3 modules and works great. I tested it also with tkinter without any problem. So for me the solution is definitively switch to cx_freeze. I keep the thread open some time more so I can post the next updates about my cx_freeze tests.